# Why I get error "Method Range of Object _Global Failed " when refering to a range with Cells values VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I get the error "Method Range of Object _Global Failed " when I refer to the Range as `Range(Cells(row, 1)).Select` then only I get the error.

But If I refer to it as `Range("A2").select` then I don't get the error.

I tried giving full path as  `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("FD").Range(Cells(row, 1)).Select` but it didn't work either.

Below is the function I'm using,

```
Function copyTBdata()

Dim FD As Worksheet, CD As Worksheet
Set FD = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("FD")


Dim row As Long

row = (ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FD").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row) + 1
   

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("TB").Activate
Range("AD2", Range("AD2").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight)).Copy

FD.Activate
Range(Cells(row, 1)).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    


End Function
```

how to fix this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("FD").Range(Cells(row, 1)).Select` the `Cells` is not qualified so will refer to the active sheet. Best to use references wherever possible.

```vb
Sub copyTBdata()

    Dim wsFD As Worksheet, wsTB As Worksheet
    Dim rowno As Long

    Set wsFD = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("FD")
    Set wsTB = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("TB")
    
    With wsFD
        rowno = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row + 1
    End With
    
    With wsTB
         .Range("AD2", .Range("AD2").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight)).Copy
         wsFD.Range("A" & rowno).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    End With
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
   
End Sub
```